# Quit Menu in the RCP Application is disabled in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, menu, swt, rcp, quit

[image]

I know Eclipse automatically maps the About, Preferences and Quit actions to the Application Menu. But only quit has some problem(which is seems to be disabled but ⌘+Q working fine), other two are working fine.

In **Application.e4xmi**

Command id 
**org.eclipse.ui.file.exit**

Binding Table:
KeyBinding **M1+Q**

**Handler**
command is mapped to above mentioned quit command, **ClassUri** is mapped to QuitHandler

**handledMenuItem** is created with command mapped to same

The Quit menu is disabled unfortunately, but Cmd Q is working fine. Any suggestions to **enable the Quit menu** is appreciated.

Comment: Is the HandledMenuItem somewhere in the Main Menu for the main Trimmed Window? If it is recognized it will be removed from the Main Menu and used in the application menu.

Comment: it is getting removed from the main menu, the only problem here is that the quit menu is disabled. But the key binding is working fine.

Comment: Is the handler defined in the 'top level' handlers list (rather than in a Window or something)? Does it have a @CanExecute that might be returning false? We are talking about the 'Quit XXXX' menu item that appears at the bottom of the Application menu? Does the menu item show the Cmd+Q shortcut at the right?

Comment: We are not using @CanExecute in the handler, i have added images of the structure and also how it is getting displayed in mac. Please go through the same.

Comment: Sorry, can't think of anything else. I have several e4 apps on my Mac and this works for all of them so it can be made to work (Eclipse 4.3.2, Mac 10.9.2).

Comment: Same OS and eclipse version (Eclipse 4.3.2, Mac 10.9.2). If i create a sample RCP application, i can see the 'Quit xxx' enabled and working fine. But in my application something is blocking to get it enabled unfortunately